# Wine, TI Connect installation errors

Tags: 12.04, wine

I've installed wine on my laptop on a ubuntu 12.04 os, I've successfully installed spotify on my computer, and it does work.  When I try to install the TI connect software it installs it, but it won't run, saying that it may need to be re-installed.

Comment: What version of Wine are you using, and if you run it via the terminal, what error codes does the program possibly give you?

Comment: I have Wine version 1.4.1.4-0ubuntu4.1, I'm new to ubuntu so how do you run it via terminal?

Comment: You'll need to start the terminal (ctrl+alt+T), then enter `wine name/of/executable.exe`, replacing "name/of/executable.exe" with the path to the ti connect program.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use TiLP instead of Ti Connect. TiLP should work without problems on Ubuntu.

Install it using this command

```
sudo apt-get install tilp2
```